# UTF-8 with code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, utf-8

I'm using a UTF8_unicode database that I was using previously with a home-made code. So the database is perfectly fine, I can fetch my data and display it without problems.

I'm trying to switch to CodeIgniter. I've changed database.php and config.php to make it display UTF8 BUT it just doesn't work. I have to use utf8_decode inside of my controllers if I want to be able to display my data correctly. Any idea why? It's driving me insane right now.

Comment: with `$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';` and `$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci'` in your `app/config/database.php` should be enough, i'm uncertain if `utf8_decode` is useful in this case.

Comment: @complex857 yes it should be enough, but it's not. I've tried inserting data through CodeIgniter's Active Records and it insert it like plain data (if I go in Mysql it displays "ééééééàààuùuü" (which are not UTF8 characters)).

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? it is displaying anything? what? is it just a page encoding issue - can you change the browser encoding and see it?

Comment: it's displaying messy characters (Ã©Ã©Ã©). Chagning the browser encoding doesn't do much. If I query the database, not using code igniter, it displays correctly.

Comment: also the data I add to my database through Code Igniter is in ISO.

Comment: Try writing your output to a file, see what you get. If it works, try setting the page header to UTF8 (`$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`)

Comment: I found the problem. It comes from codeIgniter using SET NAMES utf8

Answer (score 1):

After spending lots of time, I got solution of this problem.

1) Open your PHPMyAdmin database.

2) Select your database.

3) After select your table.

4) Goto structure then clicks on change which column you want to store that type of data.

5) goto Collation and change the type from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_general_ci.

This logic corrected my data

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the web a lot I've found my solution!

CodeIgniter uses `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")` to communicate with the mysql server. So if you've never used this before it mess everything. I don't know how I'm going to deal with it.

I also did :

```
ALTER TABLE p1x3l_posts MODIFY texte TEXT character set latin1;
ALTER TABLE p1x3l_posts MODIFY texte BLOB;
ALTER TABLE p1x3l_posts MODIFY texte TEXT character set utf8;
```

and it corrected my data.